# TS is throwing error on generic type which extending from interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have three interfaces:

**A.ts**

```js
export interface A {
    requestID: number;
    createdUser: string;
    createdDate: string;
    text: string
}
```

**B.ts**

```js
export interface B {
    requestID: number;
    createdUser: string;
    createdDate: string;
    department: string;
    emailID: string;
}
```

**AB.ts**

```js
export interface AB extends A, B {
    requestType: string;
    assignedUser: string;
}
```

Now, I am using these interfaces in a generic method to do some sorting functionality:

```js
function sort<T extends AB | A | B>(requests: T[], columnName: string) {
    switch columnName {
        case "requestID": {
            requests.sort((a, b) => a.requestID > b.requestID ? 1 : -1);
        } case "requestType": {
            requests.sort((a, b) => a.requestType > b.requestType ? 1 : -1);
            break;
        } case "text": {
            requests.sort((a, b) => a.text > b.text ? 1 : -1);
            break;
        } case "department": {
            requests.sort((a, b) => a.department > b.department ? 1 : -1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but, I am getting the below error:

```
Property 'requestType' does not exist on type 'AB | A | B'.
```

Since, `requests` is of type `T`, which is a generic (and it is extending from `AB`, `A` and `B`), I believe it should have the `requestType` attribute and it should not throw this error. Am I somewhere wrong?

Comment: `requestType` does not exist on `A`, so it cannot be safely accessed on an object that is `A | B | AB`. You can *narrow* the type by checking `if (requests.length && 'requestType' in requests[0]) { /* compiler infers AB in this block */}`. You can also discriminate a union of types by `switch`ing on a property that can reliably distinguish between them. But you have to do one or the other, because any given `columnName` might not exist for the given array of that generic type.

Comment: Also note that you probably want a second generic parameter `K extends keyof T` and make the `columnName` parameter of type `K`.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is wery simple, you don't need to handle different columns differently
Just use a totally generic sorter:

```
function sort<T, K extends keyof T>(list: T[], prop: K) {
    return list.sort((a, b) => a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : -1);
}
```

or call it inside your custom sorter (with added `K extends keyof T`) to sort